# Is there a way to for UDP .net socket to release a bound port when the socket is closed?

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, windows-7, udp

For this question, I'm running windows 7 64 bit, .net framework 3.5

What I really want to know is

1. Is there a way to unbind/release a port that has been bound?
2. When I set the socketoption reuse address I am able to bind to the port but I never receive data using that address/port?

I'm looking at what ports are bound using netstat -apd udp

The test code I'm using is below, normally I would not close the port after receiving one packet.

```
EndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(state.IPAddress, state.Port);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);                    
socket.Bind(endpoint);


ReadStateObject stateObject = new ReadStateObject();
stateObject.socket = socket;
stateObject.Port = state.Port;
stateObject.IPAddress = state.IPAddress;
stateObject.BurstDataReceivedEvent = state.BurstDataReceivedEvent;
stateObject.shutdownRequested = state.StopRequestedEvent;
socket.BeginReceiveFrom(stateObject.buffer,
                        0,
                        stateObject.buffer.Length,
                        SocketFlags.None, // Was 0 which is likely the same enumeration but this is clearer
                        ref endpoint,
                        new AsyncCallback(BurstUdpListener.SocketBeginReceiveAsyncCallback),
                         stateObject);

// wait for read to complete... or the thread to be asked to stop
while (stateObject.readFinished.WaitOne(100, false) == false)
{
    // has this thread been requested to stop? if so, cancel the pending read
    if (state.StopRequestedEvent.WaitOne(1, false) == true)
    {
        stop = true;
        break;
     }
 }

 socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
 socket.Close();
 socket = null;



    private static void SocketBeginReceiveAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

            if (ar.IsCompleted)
            {
                ReadStateObject state = ar.AsyncState as ReadStateObject;
                if (state != null)
                {
                    if (state.shutdownRequested.WaitOne(1, false))
                        return;
                    EndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(state.IPAddress, state.Port);
                    int bytesReceived = state.socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref endpoint); // for some reason throws error here on changes to settings
                    if (state.BurstDataReceivedEvent != null)
                    {
                        state.BurstDataReceivedEvent(null, new BurstDataReceivedEventArgs(state.buffer, bytesReceived));
                    }
                    state.readFinished.Set();
                }

         }            

 }
```

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol. This question makes no sense.

Comment: The port is still bound when I close the socket as netstat shows me.  When I attempt to rebind I'll get in in use exception, unless I have reuse address socket option set.  That makes sense.  If I have reuse address socket option set I never recieve the packets the after closing and opening/binding to the port.

Comment: Edited the question to get rid of connection as you are correct that UDP is a connectionless protocol.  What I really want to know is 1) Is there a way to unbind/release a port that has been bound. 2) When I set the socketoption reuse address I am able to bind to the port but I never receive data using that address/port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port should be released when `close()` is called, so it sounds like either `close()` is not being called or it is not succeeding.

Remove the `shutdown()` call as that does not really apply to UDP.

Check the error return of `close()` to make sure both that it is being called and that it is returning success.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  close() doesn't have a return type? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: In the method case, it should throw an exception if the underlying `closesocket()` function returned an error.  So just make sure you are actually reaching that statement and catching any exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I can step through the code and see he call to socket.close() getting hit and returning without throwing an exception.

Comment: But after the `close()`, `netstat -a -u -p -n` still shows that port number as being bound to that process?

Comment: I think you mean -b instead of -u  but the answer is yes.

Comment: I think there is a reference to the socket still being kept when using the Async receive methods on thtoe close as I created a simpler threaded socket class and when I close the port it is no longer bound to the process.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the linux syntax.  The windows equivalent would be `netstat -a -b -n -p udp -o`, or maybe leave out the `-b` to avoid the need for administrative rights.  What about the call to `WaitOne` in `SocketBeginReceiveAsyncCallback`?  Is there any chance that is blocking?  [Looks like our posts crossed-paths.]

Comment: No, I can break point the code and see that the code close is being hit.

Comment: I was asking about `WaitOne` in the callback, which might possibly be running on a separate thread.